# When jumping whilst moving the jump isn't as high

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im a beginner learning unity 2d and Im making a platformer type game. When I try jumping while moving the jump is a lot smaller than when Im standing still and jumping. The jump is also quite rapid and just goes up really quickly. I think it is something to do with the speed maybe cancelling it out but I don't know. Here is the code:

void Update()
{

```
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
     {
         
         isLeftPressed = true;
     }
     else
     {
         
         isLeftPressed = false;
     }


  
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
     {
         
         isRightPressed = true;
     }
     else
     {
         // Rightkey(A) isnt being pressed
         isRightPressed = false;
     }


    
     if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
         
         isSpaceBarPressed = true;
     }
  
     if (!IsGrounded())
     {
        
        
         isSpaceBarPressed = false;
     }


 }

 private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (isLeftPressed)
     {
         moveLeft();
     }
     
     else if (isRightPressed)
     {     
         moveRight();
     }
   
     else
     {
         _rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, _rigidbody2d.velocity.y);
     }
     if (isSpaceBarPressed)
     { 
         Jump();
     }
 }  
 
 private void moveLeft()
 {
     _rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(-playerSpeed, 0);
 }

 private void moveRight()
 {
     _rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(playerSpeed, 0);
 }


 private void Jump()
 {

     _rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody2d.velocity.x, 
    playerJumpHieght); 
 }
```

If anyone had any ideas on how to fix this that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you move left or right you overwrite the vertical velocity with 0. Same with jumping, you're overwriting the horizontal velocity with 0. Thus each of them cancels the other.

Comment: Thanks it worked super well. i look at it now and it seems so obvious. Thanks again